# WatchKey is always null

Tags: java, watch

I try to watch certain files for changes.
But the `WatchKey` I get from `watch_object.watch_service.poll(16, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);` is always `null`.
Not a single error is printed to the console, so I'm a bit lost.

```
public class FileWatcher implements Runnable {

    public FileWatcher() {
    }

    static public class Watch_Object {
        public File file;
        public WatchService watch_service;
    }

    static public HashMap<Object, Watch_Object> watched_files = new HashMap<>();

    static public boolean is_running = false;


    static public synchronized void watch(Object obj, String filename) {

        File file = new File(filename);

        if (file.exists()) {

            try {

                WatchService watcher = null;
                watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

                Watch_Object watch_object = new Watch_Object();
                watch_object.file = file;
                watch_object.watch_service = watcher;

                watched_files.put(obj, watch_object); 

                Path path = file.toPath().getParent();
                path.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);

                if (!is_running) {
                    (new Thread(new FileWatcher())).start();
                    is_running = true;
                }


            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

        }
        else {
            // Error
        }

    }



    @Override
    public void run() {

        try  {
            while (true) {
                synchronized(this) {

                    for (Watch_Object watch_object : watched_files.values()) {

                        WatchKey key = watch_object.watch_service.poll(16, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

                        System.out.println("A");

                        if (key != null) {

                            System.out.println("B");

                        }

                    }

                }
                Thread.sleep(16);    
            }
        } 
        catch (Throwable e) {
            // Log or rethrow the error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

To run it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // the obj is WIP, just use null for now
    watch(null, "/Users/doekewartena/Desktop/test_image.png");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to prefix this answer by saying [`WatchService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) is highly implementation-dependent:

> ### Platform dependencies
>
> The implementation that observes events from the file system is intended to map directly on to the native file event notification facility where available, or to use a primitive mechanism, such as polling, when a native facility is not available. Consequently, many of the details on how events are detected, their timeliness, and whether their ordering is preserved are highly implementation specific. For example, when a file in a watched directory is modified then it may result in a single `ENTRY_MODIFY` event in some implementations but several events in other implementations. Short-lived files (meaning files that are deleted very quickly after they are created) may not be detected by primitive implementations that periodically poll the file system to detect changes.
>
> If a watched file is not located on a local storage device then it is implementation specific if changes to the file can be detected. In particular, it is not required that changes to files carried out on remote systems be detected.

---

You mention `WatchService.poll` is always returning `null`. This is not completely surprising as both [`poll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/WatchService.html#poll()) and [`poll(long,TimeUnit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/WatchService.html#poll(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) will return `null` if there are no events to process—standard queue-like behavior. But you say you're *always* getting `null`, even when you have modified the watched file<sup>*</sup>. Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the problem using OpenJDK 11.0.2 (or JDK 1.8.0_202), Windows 10, and a local storage device.

<sup>*This was said in the question comments before they got cleaned up.</sup>

When trying your code I observed a `B` being printed out to console. Granted, it wasn't easy to see it as printing `A` out every `16` milliseconds was overwhelming, but it was there. There was one issue, though, in that after the first modification event it wouldn't report any more. This leads me into a few of remarks about your code.

1. You don't call [`WatchKey.reset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/WatchKey.html#reset()).

It's important to call this method when done processing the `WatchKey`. The method marks the `WatchKey` as ready to detect new events. Without this call you won't observe subsequent events.

2. You don't [poll the events](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/WatchKey.html#pollEvents()) of the `WatchKey`.

In attempt to fix the not-seeing-subsequent-events problem, I naively added a call to `reset()` without doing anything else. This led to an overwhelming number of `B`s being printed to console. I was confused because I had only modified the file once, but then I read the documentation of `WatchKey.reset` (**emphasis** mine):

> Resets this watch key.
>
> If this watch key has been cancelled or this watch key is already in the ready state then invoking this method has no effect. **Otherwise if there are pending events for the object then this watch key is immediately re-queued to the watch service.** If there are no pending events then the watch key is put into the ready state and will remain in that state until an event is detected or the watch key is cancelled.

What I was seeing was simply the same event over and over because I was never processing it. After adding a call to [`WatchEvent.pollEvents()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/WatchKey.html#pollEvents()) I was no longer being spammed with `B`s.

3. You create a new `WatchService` for each file you want to watch.

You appear to want a class that can watch an arbitrary number of files (and only those files). This doesn't require a `WatchService` per file as you can register multiple directories with the same `WatchService`. A case you would be *required* to use multiple `WatchService`s would if the files come from different `FileSystem`s. However, your code consistently uses the [default file system](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html#getDefault()).

Using the same `WatchService` also removes the need to use `poll`. I'd assume the reason you use `poll` currently is because you need to check each `WatchService`. As there is only one now you can use the blocking [`WatchService.take()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/WatchService.html#take()) method instead.

---

Here's a small example doing, I believe, what you want. I can't promise it's perfect as it's not been thoroughly tested. Nor can I promise it will work on your computer.

```
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.ClosedWatchServiceException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystem;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

/**
 * Watches files for modification events, but not for creation, 
 * deletion, or overflow events.
 */
public class FileWatcher implements Closeable, Runnable {

    private final List<BiConsumer<? super FileWatcher, ? super Path>> handlers 
            = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private final Map<Path, Registry> registeredDirs = new HashMap<>();
    private final Set<Path> watchedFiles = new HashSet<>();

    private final AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean();
    private final FileSystem fileSystem;
    private final WatchService service;

    public FileWatcher(FileSystem fs) throws IOException {
        service = fs.newWatchService();
        fileSystem = fs;
    }

    public FileSystem getFileSystem() {
        return fileSystem;
    }

    public boolean startWatching(Path file) throws IOException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(file);
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (watchedFiles.add(file)) {
                Path directory = file.getParent();
                if (registeredDirs.containsKey(directory)) {
                    registeredDirs.get(directory).incrementCount();
                } else {
                    try {
                        WatchKey key = directory.register(service, ENTRY_MODIFY);
                        registeredDirs.put(directory, new Registry(key));
                    } catch (ClosedWatchServiceException | IllegalArgumentException
                            | IOException | SecurityException ex) {
                        watchedFiles.remove(file);
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean stopWatching(Path file) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(file);
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (watchedFiles.remove(file)) {
                Path directory = file.getParent();
                Registry registry = registeredDirs.get(directory);
                if (registry.decrementCount()) {
                    registeredDirs.remove(directory);
                    registry.cancelKey();
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void addHandler(BiConsumer<? super FileWatcher, ? super Path> handler) {
        handlers.add(Objects.requireNonNull(handler));
    }

    public void removeHandler(BiConsumer<? super FileWatcher, ? super Path> handler) {
        handlers.remove(Objects.requireNonNull(handler));
    }

    private void fireModifyEvent(Path source) {
        for (BiConsumer<? super FileWatcher, ? super Path> handler : handlers) {
            try {
                handler.accept(this, source);
            } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().getUncaughtExceptionHandler()
                        .uncaughtException(Thread.currentThread(), ex);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        service.close();
        synchronized (lock) {
            registeredDirs.clear();
            watchedFiles.clear();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (running.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            try {
                while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                    WatchKey key = service.take();
                    for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                        Path source = ((Path) key.watchable())
                                .resolve((Path) event.context());
                        boolean isWatched;
                        synchronized (lock) {
                            isWatched = watchedFiles.contains(source);
                        }
                        if (isWatched) {
                            fireModifyEvent(source);
                        }
                    }
                    key.reset();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
            } finally {
                running.set(false);
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("already running");
        }
    }

    private static class Registry {

        private final WatchKey key;
        private int count;

        private Registry(WatchKey key) {
            this.key = key;
            incrementCount();
        }

        private void incrementCount() {
            count++;
        }

        private boolean decrementCount() {
            return --count <= 0;
        }

        private void cancelKey() {
            key.cancel();
        }

    }

}
```

And a small application using the above `FileWatcher`:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.LinkOption;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path file = chooseFile();
        if (file == null) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Entered \"" + file + "\"");

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        try (FileWatcher watcher = new FileWatcher(FileSystems.getDefault())) {
            Future<?> task = executor.submit(watcher);
            executor.shutdown();

            watcher.addHandler((fw, path) -> System.out.println("File modified: " + path));

            watcher.startWatching(file);

            waitForExit();
            task.cancel(true);
        } finally {
            executor.shutdownNow();
        }
    }

    private static Path chooseFile() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter file (or 'exit' to exit application): ");
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            if ("exit".equalsIgnoreCase(line.trim())) {
                return null;
            }
            Path file = Paths.get(line).toAbsolutePath().normalize();
            if (Files.isRegularFile(file, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
                return file;
            }
            System.out.println("File must exist and be a regular file. Try again.");
        }
    }

    private static void waitForExit() {
        System.out.println("\nType 'exit' to exit the application.");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            if ("exit".equalsIgnoreCase(line.trim())) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And a GIF of it in action:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a working code which I am using, it closely resembles your code. I hope this helps.

```
 public void watchDirectory(Path dir) {
    logger.info("Watching directory {} for new Files", dir);

    WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
    registerRecursive(dir, watchService);
    WatchKey key;
    while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
      key.pollEvents();
      executorService.submit(this::performAction);
      boolean reset = key.reset();
      if (!reset) {
        logger.error("Could not reset the WatchKey");
        throw new RunTimeException("Could not reset the WatchKey");
      }
    }

  }

  private void performAction() {
    // Your code after an event is registered
  }

  private void registerRecursive(Path root, WatchService watchService) throws IOException {
    Files.walkFileTree(root, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

      @Override
      public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        dir.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
      }
    });
  }
```